# Limit of $\exp(i\log x)$ for $x \to 0$

Tags: calculus, complex-integration

Can the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} x^i = \lim_{x\to 0} \exp( i \log x )$$ be defined? I know that in "classical" sense this equals $$x^i = \cos\log x + i \sin\log x$$ so the limit doesn't exist, but can it be defined in some distribution sense, so it makes some sense if the expression shows up in some integral, or something of the sort?

I apologize if the question is kinda vague; the problem I'm working on includes an integral of a total derivative of $ e^{i f(x) + i \log x}$ from $0$ to $X$, which *should* exist (based on some other considerations), but I don't know how to evaluate it, since at one boundary I have $\lim_{x\to 0} e^{i f(x) +i \log x}$ ($f(x)$ is complex in general, but at $x\to 0$ it converges to a real value). Any help (however vague) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The limit doesn't exist in the classical sense, but the function is bounded as you go to $0$ which seems like it should be good enough for your integral. Split your integral into a part that's close to $0$ on a short path and the rest. On the short part, bound it by the max of the function times the length of the path. Then let the short part get smaller and smaller.

Comment: Hi. It might be good to show us this integral